# TO_NUMBER for Whole Number

Tags: sql, oracle, powerbi

I have the following function:

```
TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(FF9.SEQ, 1, LENGTH(FF9.SEQ) - 2))
```

This function cuts the number column SEQ by 2 digits.
The result is somehow a decimal number. I need a whole number as a result.
Is there any chance to get this result?

it is based on oracle DB

Comment: Can you show us few examples from column SEQ ? Also share with us the type of that column...

Answer (score 1):

If you need a whole number, then `ROUND` it or `TRUNC` it.

As if you expect the `SEQ` to have only 2 decimals, while some of them don't. But - why would you reinvent the wheel and "remove decimals" using `SUBSTR`? There are other function you could / should use.